# Sql server 2012 installation error

Tags: sql-server-2012

one of my friends is currently installing Sql server 2012 and she encountered at "shared features" step. At "Shared features" step, normal installation would give user to select

- Management tool -Basic
- Sql Client Connectivity SDK
  etc depending on server version, right? She can see these features but the problem is these features are disabled( she can't select them).

I do search a lot from Google but all I can find is installation guide. Sorry for not providing screen shots. I believe you guys can help. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is this a new default install or a named instance install?

Comment: @Greenstone Walker, I guess she might have some sql server already installed before. Then she tried to install 2012 and meet with that error. As she is trying to install in desktop , I can't try myself except giving advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The SDK is not required.
- The SQL Management Studio is standalone since some time and can be downloaded [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) and just be installed after.

Additionally you could try the [unattend mode](http://www.matthanson.ca/2012/04/sql-server-2012-unattended-installation/) to force installation...

Comment: Fisher lennybacon, thanks for the answer ,Sir. Will try and give u reply back.

Comment: @KyawZinThant Would you like to share your results?